# filter variables whose column names contain pattern

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to filter out `NA`, `NaN` and `Inf` values out of a `tbl` using `dyplr`'s `filter` function.

The trick is that I only want to apply the filter to columns whose names contain a specific pattern. The pattern is: r1, r2, r3, etc.

I have tried to combine `grep` and `filter` to achieve this, but can't get it to work. My current code looks like this:

```
filter_(!is.na(grep("r[1-9]", colnames(DF), value = TRUE)) 
& !is.infinite(grep("r[1-9]", colnames(DF), value = TRUE)) 
& !is.nan(grep("r[1-9]", colnames(DF), value = TRUE)))
```

However, this code returns a warning message: "Truncating vector to length 1." 
And the data returned is unfiltered.

I suspect that it's the `is.na` functions here that are causing the problem, because I've seen an example online where you can apply `grep` to `filter` using a normal condition (i.e. `condition == value`) and not a condition based on `is.na`

Comment: Can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your dataset?

Comment: I believe that the problem is that you are testing `colnames(DF)` for `NA`, `NaN` and `Inf`, when it should be the values in those columns. (The ones that match your pattern `r[1-9]`.)

Answer (score 8):

`dplyr` provides `matches()` that is useful for this

Example 1: How `matches()` work?

```
library(dplyr)

# remove columns that start with "mp"
mtcars %>% select(-matches("mp"))

# keep columns that start with "mp"
mtcars %>% select(matches("mp"))
```

Example 2: Using `matches()` in the context of your request but using a MWE

```
# Create a dummy dataset
data = tibble(id = c("John","Paul","George","Ringo"),
              r1 = c(1,2,NA,NA), 
              r2 = c(1,2,NA,4),
              s1 = c(1,NA,3,4))

# Filter NAs in columns that start with r followed by a number
data %>% filter_at(vars(matches("r[0-9]")), all_vars(!is.na(.)))
```

Comment: I've just realised I did not complete the example. Now its complete, @anita-mcgill

Answer (score 5):

With `dplyr`, you can use the `filter_at` function:

```
dat %>% filter_at(vars(matches("^r[1-9]")), all_vars(is.finite(.)))
```

Using @lmo's sample data, the result is:

> ```
>   r1 r2         d
> 1  1  1 0.2774292
> ```

Comment: Hi, this works. But I've now discovered a further issue which can be resolved by only filtering the `Inf` and `NaN` values (and leaving in `NA`). To do this can I replace the second argument with `all_vars(!is.infinite(.)) & all_vars(!is.nan(.))`

Comment: @AnitaMcGill above I posted a solution that points to your current problem

Answer (score 4):

Here is a base R method to filter rows, comparing specific columns.

```
# sample data
set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame(r1=c(NA, 1,NaN, 5, Inf), r2=c(NA, 1,NaN, NA, Inf), d=rnorm(5))
```

this data set looks like

```
dat
   r1  r2          d
1  NA  NA -1.2070657
2   1   1  0.2774292
3 NaN NaN  1.0844412
4   5  NA -2.3456977
5 Inf Inf  0.4291247
```

We will check the first two columns and ignore the third column. Notice that the only row that should remain is row 2.

```
dat[Reduce("&", lapply(dat[grep("^r", names(dat))], is.finite)),]
  r1 r2         d
2  1  1 0.2774292
```

Here, a data.frame that is subset using `grep` to select the appropriate columns (1 and 2) is fed to `lapply`. The regex "^r" says only include variables whose names that start with "r". In the `lapply` loop, each vector is checked using `is.finite`. This function returns FALSE for NA, NaN, and Inf. The resulting list of logical vectors is fed to Reduce` which returns a logical vector the length of the number of rows of the data.frame where an element is TRUE if and only if every element in a row is finite.